# Xamarin.Android app with MvvmCross and Pixate

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, pixate

I am currently experimenting with Pixate, trying to add to our existing app that is built with Xamarin.Android and uses MvvmCross.  Without Pixate, the app works correctly.  As soon as I make the init call for Pixate, Mvvmcross will throw null exceptions in MvxSpinner method calls, and the app doesn't seem to bind to the list view or spinner.  I am wondering if there is anyone that has a working Xamarin Android application that uses both Mvvmcross and Pixate, it seems to me there's a conflict going on between the two libraries.  Just wanted to confirm and see if anyone else experience similar issues.  Thanks!

Comment: Not an exact answer, but can lead you to a solution. Pixate is proxying the adapter in order to style nth-child elements. See https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android/blob/master/pixate-freestyle/src/com/pixate/freestyle/PXHierarchyListener.java#L232

Since both the ListView and the Spinner extends from AdapterView, my guess would be that the conflict is something in that area.

Comment: Thanks @sgibly for pointing me to the right direction.  We will have to look further in that direction.

Comment: No problem. If you find a solution that requires some code changes, feel free to submit a pull request and I'll take a look.